# c# calculator foresign change?

Tags: c#

Good day, I'm an amateur programmer and I'm trying to make a calculator. I have a button which changes the foresign of a value in a textBox.
Here's my logic:

```
textBox1.Text = (double.Parse(textBox1.Text) * (-1)).ToString();
```

The problem is, that when the button is pressed, the sign changes, but the "**-**" sign is placed at the end of the value.
Is it possible somehow to do this with a `for` cycle?

Here's my calculator:
[image]

Comment: What's your locale? Some locales will display it at the end.

Comment: Is it possible that your system locale formats numbers with the negative sign at the end of the number? If so, then the `ToString` method will respect that when it converts the negative number to a string.

Comment: textBox1.Text="-"+textBox1.Text try?

Comment: Try `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: there is no ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 2):

You can force that the minus appears at the beginning by using the overload of [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045(v=vs.110).aspx) with `System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` or your desired format:

```
double d;
if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out d))
{
    d = -d;
    textBox1.Text = d.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to _parse_ it with that culture as well, otherwise clicking that button twice might be a problem.

Comment: @VigiMenyhártGyula: sorry, what happens instead?

Comment: Gives me error messages, NumberStyles does not exist in the current context, etc.

Comment: @VigiMenyhártGyula: It's in the same namespace. Just add `using System.Globalization` to the top of your code file.

Comment: I added your code, still same thing happens just like with mine